# Laravel paginate with only first result

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

i'm kinda new to Laravel so I hope the question is clear enough.

I have a table with Users and another table with Tasks.

In my User model I have the following :

```
public function tasks() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User' , 'id');
}
```

I can do the following to retrieve a single user from the DB

```
$users = \App\User::find(1)->tasks()->paginate();
```

but i get

```
{"current_page":1,"data":[{"id":1,"name":"Ed","email":"mail@weqweqeq.com","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"tasks":[{"id":1,"name":"Ed","email":"mail@weqweqeq.com","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]},{"id":2,"name":"Alyse","email":"mail@rxygewe.com","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"tasks":[]}],"first_page_url":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8000?page=1","from":1,"last_page":1,"last_page_url":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8000?page=1","next_page_url":null,"path":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8000","per_page":15,"prev_page_url":null,"to":2,"total":2}
```

I've also tried :

```
    $users = \App\User::with(['tasks' => function($q) {
        $q->first();
    }])->paginate();
```

but the tasks property is empty

My question is how I can get all the users but only with first task and paginate to work?

Tasks table

```
1   id(Primary) bigint(20)      UNSIGNED    No  None        AUTO_INCREMENT
2   created_at  timestamp           Yes NULL        
3   updated_at  timestamp           Yes NULL        
4   task_name   varchar(255)    utf8mb4_unicode_ci      No  None        
5   user_id(Index)  bigint(20)      UNSIGNED    No  None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model relationship is defined incorrectly.  You have associated a User with many Users.
https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

```php
public function tasks() {
    // a User ($this) has many Tasks
    return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
}
```

Also, be careful when using `->first()` as the order is not guaranteed unless specified.

```php
$users = \App\User::with(['tasks' => function($q) {
    // get the most recently created task
    $q->latest()->first();
}])->paginate();
```

Answer (score 0):

for another example

```
$getData = $User::where('code_transaction',$code)->first();

$pag = $getData->paginate(10);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.